# Point of Intersection

Tags: calculus

Consider the two curves given in parametric form by
$a(t) = (t^2 − t, t^2 + t)$ and $b(t) = (t + t^2, t − t^2)$ for $t ∈ \Bbb{R}.$

i) Find the two points of intersection of the curves.

I figured $(0,0)$ is one, but the solutions also mention $(2,0)$. I don't know how to get $(2,0)$.

Are the solutions wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be slightly confusing you to use $t$ as both parameters, so I have used $t$ and $s$
$$
a(t) = (t^2 − t, t^2 + t) \hspace{1cm} t \in \Bbb{R} \\
b(s) = (s + s^2, s - s^2) \hspace{1cm} s \in \Bbb{R}
$$

Lets say that these curves intersect when $t = t_0$ and $s = s_0$
So we are now solving
$$
t_0^2 − t_0 = s_0 + s_0^2 \\
t_0^2 + t_0 = s_0 - s_0^2
$$
You eventually arrive at $s_0 = s_0^4$, which has solutions $s_0 = 0, s_0 = 1$
Plugging these into $b(s)$ you arrive at $b(0) = (0, 0)$ and $b(1) = (2, 0)$